# refresh(update) widget in Nuke (vfx soft)

Tags: python, python-2.7, widget, pyside, nuke

I  need refresh(update) GUI widget(pySide) in Nuke(compositing software) after load or save nuke script.
callback: nuke.addOnScriptSave() and nuke.addOnScriptLoad()

```
import nuke
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from nukescripts import panels


class Info(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)      
        self.initUI()

    def scriptName(self): 
        sName = (nuke.root().name()).split('/')#split name from root
        return sName


    def initUI(self): 

        self.lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel("script name : " , self)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()#main layout
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl1) 
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.updateInfo()

    def updateInfo(self):

        scriptName = self.scriptName()

        self.lbl1.setText("script name : " + scriptName[-1].split('.')[0])#set name 


panels.registerWidgetAsPanel('Info', 'Info_script', 'infoscript')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to add the callback registration to your widget's `__init__`:

```python
class Info(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)      
        self.initUI()
        nuke.addOnScriptSave(self.updateInfo)
        if nuke.root().name() == 'Root' and not nuke.modified():
            # No reason to add a scriptLoad callback if opening a
            # script would spawn a new Nuke process.
            nuke.addOnScriptLoad(self.updateInfo)

    # Rest of the class definition omitted for brevity
```

This approach does have a notable downside: Because Nuke's callback registry will now contain at least one reference to the widget's `updateInfo` method, the widget can never be garbage-collected by Python. This will probably never be too big of a deal in real life, since you will probably only ever create a very small number of panel instances, but if you ever created, say, 1000 instances, you would have 1000 callbacks registered that would never be unregistered (even if the panels were closed).

Unfortunately, Nuke doesn't really give you any hooks to implement when your widget is being removed from the UI, so it's tough to have a sure-fire way of knowing it's time to unregister your callbacks. The closest you can get is probably using a `showEvent`/`hideEvent` combo and some guesswork, like so:

```python
class Info(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)      
        self.initUI()
        self.callbacksRegistered = False

    def addCallbacks(self):
        nuke.addOnScriptSave(self.updateInfo)
        if nuke.root().name() == 'Root' and not nuke.modified():
            # No reason to add a scriptLoad callback if opening a
            # script would spawn a new Nuke process.
            nuke.addOnScriptLoad(self.updateInfo)

    def removeCallbacks(self):
        self.removeOnScriptSave(self.updateInfo)
        self.removeOnScriptLoad(self.updateInfo)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not (self.callbacksRegistered or event.spontaneous()):
            self.addCallbacks()
            self.callbacksRegistered = True

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        if self.callbacksRegistered and not event.spontaneous():
            # "Spontaneous" hide events are sent when the Nuke
            # window is minimized, which we don't really care
            # about.
            self.removeCallbacks()
            self.callbacksRegistered = False

    # Rest of the class definition omitted for brevity
```

The callback registration is moved into the `showEvent` method, and the callbacks are unregistered when the widget is hidden by something other than an OS-level window operation. This is pretty reliable, except that your callbacks will also be unregistered when you change to another tab in the widget's pane (if it's docked). They will obviously be re-added when your tab is activated again though. This is a pretty minor penalty, but I still think it's worth pointing out that while this approach is pretty close to ideal, it isn't quite perfect.

Anyway, I'll leave it up to you to decide which of these two you like better, but I hope this helps.